# Checking if there is a unique transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given the vectors $x_1 = \pmatrix{2\\3} , x_2 = \pmatrix{-1\\1}, y_1 = \pmatrix{1\\1\\1}, y_2 = \pmatrix{0\\1\\-1}$   and $y_3 = \pmatrix{3\\6\\0} $

$1)$ Show that there exists exactly one linear mapping $f :\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $f(x_1) = y_1$ and $f(x_2) = y_2$

$2)$ For which $i \in \mathbb{R}$ exists a mapping $g:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ with $g(y_1) = x_1$, $g(y_2)= x_2$ and $g(y_3) = \pmatrix{i\\0}$? Is g unique?

My answers:

$1)$ Because $x_1$ and $x_2$ form a Basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (they are linearly independent and their dimension is 2) then the mapping is unique. Proving that it's linear is quite simple (all I have to do is show that the properties of a linear map apply here).

$2)$ I tried to solve this as a set of linear equations and found that $i = 3$, but didn't find a proper transformation matrix that represents this mapping. Does this mean that it's not unique?

I'd really appreciate it if someone could show me how to approach question 2 and confirm if my answer for 1 is right or not.

Comment: You can write `\pmatrix{1\\3}` to get $\pmatrix{1\\3}$.

Comment: @JohnHughes I've edited the post accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer to question 1 seems fine to me.

For question 2, notice that $y_3=3y_1+3y_2$. Therefore, as you said, $i$ has to be $3$ since it is uniquely determined by the images of $y_1$ and $y_2$. Moreover, such a map is not unique, since it is not defined on a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (for example, you can map the vector $(0,0,1)$ wherever you want).

EDIT (some two years later): as pointed out by @rax_adaam (see comments below), if we look at the second component of $g(y_3)=g(3y_1+3y_2)$, we notice that its value is $12$, and not $0$ as required. Hence, there is no $i$ doing the job.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for replying. I didn't quite understand what you meant by "not defined on a basis of R^3". Could you please explain what you meant a bit more clearly?

Comment: What I mean is that the conditions you have for the transformations only define it on a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$, namely the subspace generated by $y_1$ and $y_2$ (since, as I said above, $y_3$ is actually a member of this subspace), which has dimension $2$. Since $\mathbb{R}^3$ has dimension $3$, the transformation cannot be uniquely defined.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand what you meant.

Comment: @Leo163 I'm a bit confused, don't we have $g(y_3) = g(3y_1 + 3y_2) = 3g(y_1) + 3g(y_3) = 3x_1 + 3x_2 = \pmatrix{6 \\ 9} + \pmatrix{-3 \\ 3} = \pmatrix{3 \\ 12} \neq \pmatrix{i \\ 0}$?

Comment: @RaxAdaam oh gosh, you are right, I think I forgot to check the second component. This also explain why the OP was unable to find the linear transformation doing the job. Thank you for pointing this out!